# Change orientation of Windows 8.1 Desktop from C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, screen-orientation

Is it possible to change the orientation of the Windows 8.1 or Windows 7 desktops through C# program.. like from landscape to portrait if i select it from my application.?

I know we can get the information of width and height of the screens from Screen class in System.Windows.Forms namespace.

But, Is there any API which i can call to change the orientation.

Comment: Try these keywords "change screen orientation programmatically" in Google, you can find many hits are about Windows/C#.

Comment: The most up to date sample I can find is from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36664/Changing-Display-Settings-Programmatically), HTH.

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution provided in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms812499.aspx)

I have used the same piece of code for WPF.
Below is the code

View.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ScreenOrientation.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MaxHeight="55px" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Label Content="Change Orientation" Margin="5"></Label>
        <Button Content="Rotate Clock Wise" Margin="5" x:Name="BtnClockwise" Click="BtnClockwise_OnClick"></Button>
        <Button Content="Rotate Anti Clock Wise" Margin="5" x:Name="BtnAntiClock" Click="BtnAntiClock_OnClick"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code Behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private int[] orientationValues = new int[4]{NativeMethods.DMDO_DEFAULT,
                                                    NativeMethods.DMDO_90,
                                                    NativeMethods.DMDO_180,
                                                    NativeMethods.DMDO_270};
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BtnClockwise_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // obtain current settings
        DEVMODE dm = NativeMethods.CreateDevmode();
        GetSettings(ref dm);

        // swap height and width
        int temp = dm.dmPelsHeight;
        dm.dmPelsHeight = dm.dmPelsWidth;
        dm.dmPelsWidth = temp;

        // set the orientation value to what's next anti-clockwise
        int index = Array.IndexOf(orientationValues, (object)dm.dmDisplayOrientation);
        int newIndex = (index == 3) ? 0 : index + 1;
        dm.dmDisplayOrientation = orientationValues[newIndex];

        // switch to new settings
        ChangeSettings(dm);
    }

    private void BtnAntiClock_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // obtain current settings
        DEVMODE dm = NativeMethods.CreateDevmode();
        GetSettings(ref dm);

        // swap height and width
        int temp = dm.dmPelsHeight;
        dm.dmPelsHeight = dm.dmPelsWidth;
        dm.dmPelsWidth = temp;

        // set the orientation value to what's next anti-clockwise
        int index = Array.IndexOf(orientationValues, (object)dm.dmDisplayOrientation);
        int newIndex = (index == 3) ? 0 : index + 1;
        dm.dmDisplayOrientation = orientationValues[newIndex];

        // switch to new settings
        ChangeSettings(dm);
    }


    private int GetSettings(ref DEVMODE dm)
    {
        // helper to obtain current settings
        return GetSettings(ref dm, NativeMethods.ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS);
    }

    private int GetSettings(ref DEVMODE dm, int iModeNum)
    {
        // helper to wrap EnumDisplaySettings Win32 API
        return NativeMethods.EnumDisplaySettings(null, iModeNum, ref dm);
    }

    private void ChangeSettings(DEVMODE dm)
    {
        // helper to wrap ChangeDisplaySettings Win32 API
        int iRet = NativeMethods.ChangeDisplaySettings(ref dm, 0);
        switch (iRet)
        {
            case NativeMethods.DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL:
                break;
            case NativeMethods.DISP_CHANGE_RESTART:
                MessageBox.Show("Please restart your system");
                break;
            case NativeMethods.DISP_CHANGE_FAILED:
                MessageBox.Show("ChangeDisplaySettigns API failed");
                break;
            case NativeMethods.DISP_CHANGE_BADDUALVIEW:
                MessageBox.Show("The settings change was unsuccessful because system is DualView capable.");
                break;
            case NativeMethods.DISP_CHANGE_BADFLAGS:
                MessageBox.Show("An invalid set of flags was passed in.");
                break;
            case NativeMethods.DISP_CHANGE_BADPARAM:
                MessageBox.Show("An invalid parameter was passed in. This can include an invalid flag or combination of flags.");
                break;
            case NativeMethods.DISP_CHANGE_NOTUPDATED:
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to write settings to the registry.");
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("Unknown return value from ChangeDisplaySettings API");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The DEVMOD Struct

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct DEVMODE
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string dmDeviceName;

    public short dmSpecVersion;
    public short dmDriverVersion;
    public short dmSize;
    public short dmDriverExtra;
    public int dmFields;
    public int dmPositionX;
    public int dmPositionY;
    public int dmDisplayOrientation;
    public int dmDisplayFixedOutput;
    public short dmColor;
    public short dmDuplex;
    public short dmYResolution;
    public short dmTTOption;
    public short dmCollate;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string dmFormName;

    public short dmLogPixels;
    public short dmBitsPerPel;
    public int dmPelsWidth;
    public int dmPelsHeight;
    public int dmDisplayFlags;
    public int dmDisplayFrequency;
    public int dmICMMethod;
    public int dmICMIntent;
    public int dmMediaType;
    public int dmDitherType;
    public int dmReserved1;
    public int dmReserved2;
    public int dmPanningWidth;
    public int dmPanningHeight;
};

public class NativeMethods
{
    // PInvoke declaration for EnumDisplaySettings Win32 API
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern int EnumDisplaySettings(string lpszDeviceName, int iModeNum, ref DEVMODE lpDevMode);

    // PInvoke declaration for ChangeDisplaySettings Win32 API
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern int ChangeDisplaySettings(ref DEVMODE lpDevMode, int dwFlags);

    // helper for creating an initialized DEVMODE structure
    public static DEVMODE CreateDevmode()
    {
        DEVMODE dm = new DEVMODE();
        dm.dmDeviceName = new String(new char[32]);
        dm.dmFormName = new String(new char[32]);
        dm.dmSize = (short)Marshal.SizeOf(dm);
        return dm;
    }

    // constants
    public const int ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS = -1;
    public const int DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL = 0;
    public const int DISP_CHANGE_BADDUALVIEW = -6;
    public const int DISP_CHANGE_BADFLAGS = -4;
    public const int DISP_CHANGE_BADMODE = -2;
    public const int DISP_CHANGE_BADPARAM = -5;
    public const int DISP_CHANGE_FAILED = -1;
    public const int DISP_CHANGE_NOTUPDATED = -3;
    public const int DISP_CHANGE_RESTART = 1;
    public const int DMDO_DEFAULT = 0;
    public const int DMDO_90 = 1;
    public const int DMDO_180 = 2;
    public const int DMDO_270 = 3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The above rotates the main display. If i have the secondary display. Can I rotate only that?

Comment: Will try and let you know.

Comment: Thanks. I will also keep trying in the mean time.